# How would you implement a modal in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

1st way:

- Using angular-bootstrap

  **BUT:** it has bootsrap which is not needed in the project

2nd way:

- using ngDialog

  **BUT:** it does not have some necessary functions like 'resolve' that angular-bootstrap modal has

Modal should be implemented without bootstrap and with all the functions that angular bootstrap has.

What would you do?

Comment: I would create a `div` which looks like a modal, or just copy styles from bootstrap modal. Now I would use angular to control the visibility of the modal with some variable or route if the modal is a valid state. There is always room for improvement like defining modal as a template and reusing.

Comment: How about other functions like 'resolve'?

Comment: I'm not an expert in `angular` sorry :)